# wordpress - This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, http, https

I try to set the word press on my VPS

I have nginx server and apache server ,nginx accepts the `https/http` and redirect to apache which accepts `http`

in this case, Wordpress shows these errors,

```
The page at 'https://whitebearexample.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://whitebearexample.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.1.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So, I googled around and understood this erorr means, `https` site still requires files via `http`

Then I add

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

in  wp-config.php

I also changed in the database table name `wp_options` columns `siteurl`and `siteurl`

from `http://whitebearexample.com/` to -> `https://whitebearexample.com/`

However still error occurs, where should I fix?

Comment: The redirect doesn't help because the client rejects the request before it even tries to connect. You need to force it to remain on HTTPS if a request comes in over HTTPS.

Comment: According to your comment, I change apache server to accept https, so it works. https(nginx) -> https(apache) , I need to set certification file for both though, it is good solution, thankyou .